# Angular-meter with Iron:router

Tags: angularjs, meteor, ionic-framework, meteoric

I want to user Angular in a Meteor app - Ionic being the main reason. I am wondering is it possible to use Angular directives for UI, but still use Meteor Data Modes, and Iron Router?
Trying to decide between Meteoric + Blaze VS AngularJS + Ionic

Comment: isn't that what all these angular packages for meteor provide? (angular directives for the UI in the context of all the good meteor stuff) https://atmospherejs.com/?q=angular

Comment: thanks! i guess I've focused too much on this package https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor which does expect you do everything in Angular, except data persistence

Comment: it does not expect you to do everything in angular :)  you can use iorn:router, Blaze or even React with angular-meteor